# List all files recursively function in MFC error?

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to list all my files and folders (include sub-folders) and show it into my list box so I think about writing a recursive function to display them. But the code work well if I show all files and folders in the selecting folder, but it can not scan in sub-folders (it show only the first folder and no more). Please help me to know what is the error?

This is my function (I add it into my Dialog class)

```
void CFileListingDlg::ListFile(CString path)
{
    CFileFind hFile;
    BOOL bFound;
    CString filePath;
    bFound=hFile.FindFile(path+L"\\*.*");
    while(bFound)
    {
        bFound=hFile.FindNextFile();
        if(!hFile.IsDots())
        {
            m_lFiles.AddString(hFile.GetFilePath());

            //It work well with selecting folder if I remove this line
            //But it shows only first folder when I use it
            if(hFile.IsDirectory()) ListFile(hFile.GetFilePath()+L"\\*.*");

        }
    }
}
```

And then, I call it when click Browser button with the code

```
void CFileListingDlg::OnBnClickedBtnBrowse()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CFolderPickerDialog folderDialog(_T("E:\\Test"));
    if(folderDialog.DoModal()==IDOK)
    {
        m_eFolder.SetWindowText(folderDialog.GetPathName());
        m_lFiles.ResetContent();
        ListFile(folderDialog.GetPathName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you learn to use a debugger.

Comment: I don't think you should be appending the `*.*` in both the function call and the function body.

Comment: Thank you, Neil Butterworth, i solve it with your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the proper way to implement recursive files listing:

```
void ListFiles(const CString& sPath, CStringArray& files)
{
   CFileFind finder;

   // build a string with wildcards
   CString sWildcard(sPath);
   sWildcard += _T("\\*.*");

   BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile(sWildcard);

   while (bWorking)
   {
      bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();

      // skip . and .. files; otherwise, we'd
      // recur infinitely!

      if (finder.IsDots())
         continue;

      // if it's a directory, recursively traverse it

      if (finder.IsDirectory())
      {
         CString sFile = finder.GetFilePath();
         files.Add(sFile);
         ListFiles(sFile, files);
      }
   }

   finder.Close();
}
```